# map и numpy.zeros

Tags: python, numpy, map

```
import numpy as np
a=np.zeros((9,1))
b=np.array([1,3,7,9])
требуется
[[1],[0],[1],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[1]]
```

Хотел использовать map но никак немогу вспомнить как.

Comment: Какая связь между вектором "b" и результатом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу только предположить, что вы забыли одну единицу выставить (в позиции 7). Тогда так:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.zeros((9,1), dtype=np.int)
b=np.array([1,3,7,9])

a[b-1] = 1
print(a.tolist())
```

Вывод:

```
[[1], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1]]
```

Преобразование `tolist` тут нужно только для красоты вывода, чтобы в одну строчку напечаталось, как у вас.

Зачем тут может быть нужен `map` не представляю, просто обращаетесь к элементам массива по индексам и всё. Только учесть, что индексация идёт с нуля.

Ну, вернее, `map` можно применить, если очень хочется, конечно:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: [int(x[0] in b)], enumerate(a, 1))))
```

Вывод:

```
[[1], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1]]
```

Или ещё так, но без вложенных списков тогда:

```
print(list(map(int, map(b.__contains__, range(1, len(a)+1)))))
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: А как применить два массива  X,Y  к матрице

Comment: @gintaras.martinaitis Какие массивы, к какой матрице и как именно применить? Задайте лучше новый отдельный вопрос со всеми данными.